# Activity has leaked window in ProcessDialog

Tags: android

I am getting error : Activity com.Mobile.mytestbuddy.Register has leaked window in ProcessDialog. And I am getting this error only in Android Version 2.3.5.

**My Code onPostExecute is :** I am getting Window leaked error if condition of this code.

```
if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog = null;
}
```

I have also tried below code but It also dint work.

```
if (dialog != null) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
        }
}
```

**Code of onPreExecute:**

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Register.this, "", "Validating... Please wait...", true);
```

Comment: Some additional details needed: e.g. how are you creating the dialog(s), where are you storing the reference(s), how are you invoking the asynctask(s) and are there more than one active at any particular time?

Comment: please provide source code

Answer (score 2):

Try using given below code.

That will solve your problem.

```
    if (dialog != null) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
                dialog = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the if statement to 
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
              dialog.dismiss()
             }